# WTForms submitting dynamic fields to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm creating a series of form fields dynamically from database rows, each field will have it's own form. When a form is submitted it will update a row in the database. The problem I have is how do I match the submitted form up with the relevant row? All the form fields have the same name 'shared' but this should be ok as each field has it's own form.

views.py

```
def setting(nickname):
    user = User.query.filter_by(nickname = nickname).first()
    cars = user.cars.all()

    form_list = []
    for car in cars:
        class F(Form):
            pass
        setattr(F, 'shared', TextField(default=car.shared, label = car.carname))
        form = F(request.form, obj = car)
        form_list.append(form)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(request.form)
        flash(form.shared.data)

    return render_template('settings.html',
        user = user,
        form_list = form_list
    )
```

settings.html

```
{% for field in form_list %}
<form action="" method="post" name="share">
    {{ field.shared.label }} - {{ field.shared }}
    <input type="submit" value="share/make private"/>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must create one form instead several (one form == one request).

For example you can create form class dynamicaly with `shared_<CAR_ID>` fields names:

```
def create_cars_form_class(cars):
    form_fields = {}
    for car in cars:
        field_id = 'shared_{}'.format(car.id)
        form_fields[field_id] = TextField(label=car.carname,
                                          default=car.shared)
    return type('CarsForm', (Form,), form_fields)

def settings(nickname):
    user = User.query.filter_by(nickname = nickname).first()
    cars = user.cars.all()
    CarsForm = create_cars_form_class(cars)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        shareform = CarsForm(request.form)
        if shareform.validate():
            for name, value in shareform.data.items():
                if not name.stratswith('shared_'):
                    continue
                car_id = name.lstrip('shared_')

                # update shared there
                update_car_shared(car_id, value)
    else:
        sharefrom = CarsForm()

    return render_template('settings.html',
        user = user,
        shareform = shareform,
    )
```

and

```
{% for name, field in shareform._fields.items() %}
    {% if name.startswith('shared_') %}
        {{ field.label }}: {{ field }}<br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="share/private"/>
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer tbicr. Since posting I've been working on a slightly different solution using a form subclass. Ideally I would like to get this solution working as it's clearer in my head. If I have no luck with it I will try out your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: You can send one html form without js at one time, so to send one from your fields must have unique names `shared_<CAR_ID>` or be multi value `<shared[]>`. With single html form you can just use multi value fields but you can't get ID's in this case (realy can only if this values ID's or contain ID's). For this solution better use JS and AJAX, but without it I don't see other solution then unique field names. However it will be interesting see your solution, because in my project for static html form I have some issue.